# how to select two tables which has inner joints and union all tables

Tags: mysql

hello I am new to php I am having 2 tables I want to select 2  columns which matches accesstoken and user id column from 2 tables
for eg...I had joined (users table and sessions table ) (admin table and adminsessions) now I want to check data either one of these 2 combinations eg....if (users.id=sessions.userid) or (admin.id =adminseesions.userid) I am passing accesstoken in url and I want to match userid and accesstoken  is it possible to archive this task with union all because these 2 pairs are independent and I am expecting output as follow
if my header has userid which is in adminsessions but not in sessions tabel then I want to display the data which is in adminsessions

[image: I want to display]

or if userid from header which matches data in sessions then I want to display following details
[image: I want to display]

here I want to fetch any single row from above tables based on userid

following are the 2 tables which I want to select one of the table where accesstoken column and userid matches
[image: this is the admin session table]
[image: this is user sessions]
following are my user and admin table where I want to match one of the id column in two tables
[image: this is my user table]
[image: this is my admin table]

Comment: I hope because I don't know how it works

Comment: Please include a concrete example, how the output should look like (data, not descriptions).

Comment: updated with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible using UNION.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT userid, accesstoken, refreshtoken
      FROM adminsession
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userid, accesstoken, refreshtoken
  FROM sessions) all_sessions
 WHERE userid = :somegivenuserid;
```

This query will return all session information by `:somegivenuserid`, regardless of whether this information was found in table `adminsession` or `sessions`. In the same way you can get the user data, just that you use tables `users` and `admin`.
More information can be found in section [UNION Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) of MySQL's documentation.

Update

The OP looked for

```
SELECT userid, accesstokenexpiry 
  FROM adminsession INNER JOIN admin 
    ON adminsession.userid = admin.id 
   AND accesstoken = :accesstoken 
UNION ALL 
SELECT userid, accesstokenexpiry 
  FROM sessions INNER JOIN users 
    ON sessions.userid = users.id 
   AND accesstoken = :accesstokenusr
```

Comment: thank you I will try this and let you soon

Comment: I had slightly modified the code can you please tell me am I doing in right way because I want to check userid which is in adminsesssions and in admin also `('SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT userid, accesstoken
      FROM adminsession
      INNER JOIN admin
      ON adminsession.userid = admin.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userid, accesstoken
  FROM sessions INNER JOIN users
      ON sessions.userid = users.id and ) all_sessions
 WHERE accesstoken = :accesstoken;');`

Comment: I am having error unknown column  accesstoken but I am having column in in both sessions and adminsessions tables

Comment: I had changed your code little bit problem was solved ` SELECT userid,  accesstokenexpiry
      FROM adminsession
      INNER JOIN admin
      ON adminsession.userid = admin.id and accesstoken = :accesstoken
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userid,  accesstokenexpiry
  FROM sessions INNER JOIN users
      ON sessions.userid = users.id and accesstoken = :accesstokenusr` can you please update the answer

Comment: That query was from the answer which I deleted :-) Nice to hear, that you were able to adapt it to your needs.